# How bad is verifying a microservice in test scope? [JAVA]

Tags: java, testing, junit, microservices

So I got a task where I have to verify the REST response of a remote micro service.
For now, I built an app that calling the given REST endpoint and now I have to verify the result.

My question is, where should I write the tests? If I write into the test scope with Junit/TestNG it should be unit tests with mocked objects, right?. But in this case, I couldn't test the remote service correctly.

Is it a bad pattern to call real service from test scope using Junit?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be only bad if you intend to write a unit test. You are writing an integration test here. However, keep in mind that the tests are run on each build, so a failure in the external service would break your build.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's indeed an Integration Test.
How could I do this without breaking the code every time it fails?

Comment: Keep the integration tests separate so that they are not run during a normal build. This has nothing to do with the used technology, you can still use JUnit as test runner.

Comment: Where should I put them in this case? Out of test scope?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "test scope". They would go into another directory if you mean that.

Comment: take a look at this https://www.baeldung.com/maven-integration-test

Comment: JUnit is only a framework. Technically you can also use it to write an integration test by simply just not mocking out anything. It depends how deep you want to test and how transparent you want to make the test. I think your question is mainly about best practices of integration testing microservices if I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: @WillC Yes basically this is the main propose

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the trade-offs that you'll need to make and could generally be pretty difficult to move towards a reliable state. For instance, if you wanted to test in QA but other teams have different philosophies on what QA is and happens to use it like a local development environment, their services are probably failing more often than it probably would have otherwise. In that case, when you want to run integration tests with real services that other teams own, chances are your tests may not be too indicative whether *your* services ran correctly. It could be the service dependency failing that trips failures when testing your services.

In that scenario, I would mock out downstream services that your team does not own because its out of your control. This could be mocking it by spinning up a web service that responds with JSON or XML payloads or whatever metalanguage the service you're consuming responding with. It could also be mocking it at the *request client* level meaning the lowest level of the library that sends the request.

As an effect, that means the requests that go to your service will go through all the layers of logic in your service without any mocks to the lowest possible part where your team has control over. It's based on black box testing where the service dependencies are isolated with the assumption that the other team is properly versioning their services or providing backwards compatibility. This type of testing is the less costly to maintain if you have ever seen the testing pyramid. The gist of the pyramid is that the more integrative your tests, the costlier it is to maintain and build.

If you want even more guarantees, you can combine this with contract driven tests. Essentially, another test suite that tests downstream services and making sure that they still adhere to the payload schema that your service depends on. This way, you can decouple these two sets of tests without having to worry about all the logic that comes with it. It is also more transparent in terms of failures as you will know whether your service failed or the service dependency failed.

That would be the strategy and I would advocate for using an acceptance testing framework like Cucumber to actually do the job. There are many variants of Cucumber but essentially, you would be writing behavioral driven tests (that even the product owner can read) that is parsed by a language of your choice. See [this](https://cucumber.io/) link for details.